# Accessing Exact Target Campaign Reporting Information from the rest-api

Tags: javascript, rest-api, marketing-cloud

Is it possible via the rest api to gather campaign metrics such as `Sent`, `Opens`, `Clicks`, etc..

I have been reviewing https://code.exacttarget.com/api/fuel-api-family-hub-0, not sure if i'm missing it somewhere.

Comment: Is this specifically about an Exact Target campaign, or more generally about Salesforce campaigns? If the former, please add the exact target tag to the question.

Comment: If this answered your question - be sure to check the mark so we all know it is!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SOAP API will need to be used in order to get detailed tracking information for Jobs like Opens, Clicks, and Sent.

Details for SentEvent can be found at:
http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/retrieve_sentevent_details_for_job/

The SOAP requests for other tracking events are very similar to SentEvent, basically just switch out the ObjectType.